# Given the law of $\sup_{t\ge T_0}B_t$ when BM started from $x>0$ and $T_0=\inf\{t\ge 0: B_t=0\}$.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I have some exercises from Le Gall textbook.

(1)Let $M$ be a martingale with continuous sample paths such that $M_0=x$. We assume that $M_t\ge 0$ for every $t\to 0$ and that $M_t \to 0$ as $t\to \infty$ a.s. Show that
$$
P(\sup_{t\ge 0} M_t\ge y)=\frac{y}{x}
$$

(2)Given the law of $\sup_{t\ge T_0}B_t$ when BM started from $x>0$ and $T_0=\inf\{t\ge 0: B_t=0\}$.

(3) Assume now that $B$ is a BM started from $0$, let $\mu>0$. Using an appropriate exponential martingale, show that $\sup (B_t-\mu t)$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $2\mu$.

I have finished (1). But I am not sure (2).

I think we can just use reflection principle for (2) that is
$$
P(M_t\ge a)=2P(B_t\ge a)=2(1-P(B_1<a/\sqrt{t})=2-2\Phi(a/\sqrt{t})
$$
where $M_t=\sup_{0\le s\le t} B_s$. Does it correct?

How to do (3)?